# PHP session_write_close() does not work in NGINX

Tags: php, http, session, nginx, webserver

I'm having trouble running session_write_close() on Nginx, it has no effect.

When I access resources that take a long time to complete, the other pages of the application are blocked, waiting for the first page to finish.

I migrated my application from Apache to Nginx, in Apache it was working normally.

No information appears in the Nginx or Apache log. Does anyone know why this occurs?

Best regards.

Comment: What is you php version?

Comment: Hello Marvin! My PHP version is 7.2.7

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the same with php 7 and Nginx. You can change your cache memory, use memchached or redis.

Comment: Is it a PHP 7 problem then? Have you tried on some other version?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming nginx is running by default under the username nginx, then I would check /var/lib/php/session foder and see if it has the proper ownership. If you switched from apache, then that folder has either nobody or www-data ownership (user/group). So do a `ls -lsa /var/lib/php/session`, see who owns the folder and then do a `chown nginx:nginx /var/lib/php/session -R`. Then try again and see if it works or not.

Comment: Hello Bogdan!

I checked that the sessions folder did not exist ... So I modified the session.save_path property to /tmp, which has full permission (777) to perform the tests.
Even though the problem continues to occur, I see that PHP can write session files to the /tmp folder normally, but the session_write_close() method has no effect at all.

Comment: On Windows I'm having the same problem. Even running nginx.exe and php-cgi.exe as an administrator ... I ran a test on an Ubuntu container in Docker and it worked, I have no idea the source of the problem.

Comment: To be honest with you, I really don't know why that happens